# installing obdé library

Tags: python, collections, obd-ii

i am trying to use obd library in python for my project; however when instaling it; i get the following problem:

> 

```
PS C:\Users\DELL\Documents\OBD\project2> pip install "obd==0.7.1"
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib.util>", line 14, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 6, in <module>
    from collections import deque
ImportError: cannot import name 'deque' from 'collections' (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
PS C:\Users\DELL\Documents\OBD\project2>
```

ps: python version : 3.11.1
obd version : 0.7.1

i want to install obd library and try a simple code with it

Comment: [Possibly related](https://github.com/brendan-w/python-OBD/issues/252)?

Comment: I tried `pip install "obd==0.7.1"` and it worked fine for me. Here's the link to the output of the run: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vijayvaradan/287df9b3eb33a1f1731d439099b9aa50/raw/a52b27716f8c897c338b5ff3e3961239db9b8f93/output.log Is it possible that your Python 3.11 installation is defective?